# How to prevent bootstrap from automatically adding class='active'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use a tab-control of Bootstrap, but Bootstrap automatically sets `class="active"` on the first `li` item. How can I disable this? In my code I want to handle it myself which `li` item gets the active class.

Now am I in the situation where two tabs has the active state, obviously I don't want this.

I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.2

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': isTabVisible('elements')}">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="toggleTab('details')">@Resources.Building.Details</a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="toggleTab(category.Id)">{{category.Name}}</a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': isTabVisible('elements')}">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="toggleTab('elements')" data-ng-show="current.Id > 0">@Resources.Building.Elements</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Angular controller:

```
$scope.currentTab = 'details';

// Check for a second # in the url
var parts = window.location.hash.split('#');
if (parts.length > 1) {
    var hash = parts[2];
    $scope.currentTab = hash;
};

$scope.isTabVisible = function (categoryId) {
    return $scope.currentTab == categoryId;
}

$scope.toggleTab = function (categoryId) {
    $scope.currentTab = categoryId;
}
```

Comment: please share your code ?

Comment: @rab: I've updated my post with some code

Comment: seems like `Angular` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with AngularJS and AngularUI. It's look beautiful until you need just to modify something simple in angular-ui. My advice: Don't waste your time trying to understand a code that wasn't designed to be adjusted. Ex: in angular-ui if you use a carousel and you want to hide the arrows, you have to overload the CSS, there's no such an option like $scope.opts = [showArrows: false].

Probably it's better to write you own directive or google for one. It's not that hard to write code for tabs.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question, but since it is the top of the google results, I'll drop this answer in here...

The bootstrap documentation says `Add data-toggle="button" to toggle a button’s active state.` Removing the data-toggle attribute from the parent element results in the opposite, preventing bootstrap from adding "active" to the clicked button.

Comment: It takes 2hrs to find the working answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Bootstrap JS files? These are the one responsible for adding and removing certain pieces of the CSS code.

If you want to control all this yourself, I would suggest you remove the Bootstrap JS files and rewrite whatever you need it to do using AngularJS (as you're currently using).

This will make you lose some functionality however. There are certain versions of Bootstrap rewritten for AngularJS, like the modals.

However, if you require certain custom functionality or control about your elements, you will have to rewrite or overwrite certain parts either way.